# Divide int by 10 results strange float

Tags: java, division

I am calculating with percentage and I just divide a number by 10 and multiply by 100. Before the operation I cast to float.

So:

```
System.out.println((float)5/10*100);
System.out.println((float)6/10*100);
System.out.println((float)7/10*100);
```

And I got these:

```
50.0
60.000004
70.0
```

The question is why and how did the 60 get 4 millionths?

Comment: `0.6` is not precisely represented, most likely you meant to round the result to reflect this. `System.out.printf("%.1f%n", 6.0f/10*100);`  prints `60.0`

Comment: This is a java problem for long time. You can round it as `result = Math.round(result ×100)/100` to 2 digits behind point.

Comment: This is not a java "problem". It is a matter of how real numbers are represented on a computer in 32 bits, regardless of what language is being used

Comment: In addition to what @PeterLawrey said, you should get the correct result when you move the multiplication to the left (`(float)100*6*/10`) because all intermediate results can be represented exactly.